# iPhone - Enlarge image, keep quality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I am working on an application that allows a user to pick a photo from their camera roll or take a picture.  From the picture, I need to increase the size to be 1050x670 and keep the quality of the image.  I am able to increase the image, but the picture comes out very pixelated when I send it through email.

In the app, I will be sending the enlarged image to a server for additional processing.

Any help would be appreciated.  Here is some of code:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(1050, 670);

 CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));

    CGImageRef imageRef = [userImageView.image CGImage];

    // Compute the bytes per row of the new image
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef) / CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef) * newRect.size.width;
    bytesPerRow = 26 * 1050;//(bytesPerRow + 15) & ~15;  

    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
    newRect.size.width,
    newRect.size.height,
    8,
    bytesPerRow,
    CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, kCGInterpolationHigh);

    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef resizedImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *resizedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resizedImageRef];

    // Clean up
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(resizedImageRef);

 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(resizedImage, nil, nil, nil);

 return resizedImage;
```

Comment: What do you expect? Zooming an image does not add any details to the image, therefore it gets blurry or pixelated...

Comment: You can't add extra pixels (or detail) to image that was not there to begin with

Comment: Why can't you?  I can do it through Photoshop without pixelating the image.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Guys,

I found the problem.  The application was downsizing the image to show it to the user as a preview and then I was trying to upscale the reduced size image.  Photos on an iPhone are usually larger than 1050x670.

Answer (score 0):

The UIImagePickerController will return a downscaled image. To obtain the full size image you can use the ALAssetsLibrary.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html